# Looking for something like "facet_grid" in plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, histogram, facet-grid

I'm trying to replicate this ggplot using the plotly library:

```
ggplot(mccase, aes(x=antskad)) + geom_histogram(bins=3) + facet_grid(. ~ rating.1) + scale_y_log10()
```

I think I almost reach my objetive with:

```
mccase %>%
  group_by(rating.1) %>%
  plot_ly(y=~rating.1, x=~antskad, type='histogram') %>%
    layout(yaxis = list(type = "log", showgrid=T,  ticks="outside", autorange=TRUE))
```

However, this works correctly but I need to introduce something like the facet_grid and I have no idea how can be done.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just wrap your ggplot into ggplotly? `ggplotly(ggplot(...) + geom_histogram() + facet_grid(...))`